# How to include php code into tpl file whmcs?

Tags: php, include, smarty

I cannot seem to figure out how to get this line to work with whmcs. I want to include this in the header & footer.tpl and tried to do this with {php}{/php} but seems not te be working, and I cannot find the correct solution.

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/SafeGuardPro/protect.php';
```

Answer (score 4):

It is already solved. SOlved the issue by enable this:

{php} need to be enabled from Admin Area -> General Settings -> *Security* tab, "
Allow Smarty PHP Tags
"